# Definition of Schubert cells.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

I found two versions of definition of Schubert cells in two papers. In [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.13948.pdf), page 45, line 7 of Section 4.1, the Schubert cells are defined as
$$
{X}_{w}^{\circ} = \{ \mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{Fl}_n: \dim(F_p^{st} \cap F_q) = \# \{i \le p: w(i) \le q\}, \forall p,q \in [1,n] \}.  \quad (1)
$$
Here $\mathcal{Fl}_n$ is a flag variety and $\mathcal{F}^{st}=(0 \subseteq \langle e_1 \rangle \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \langle  e_1, \ldots, e_{n-1} \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n)$ is the standard flag.

Another version is: line 2 of Section 4.1 in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3660.pdf), the definition of Schubert cells are:
$$
{X}_{w}^{\circ} = \{ \mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{Fl}_n: \dim(\text{Proj}_{[j]}(F_i) = \# w([i]) \cap [j] ), \forall i,j \in [1,n] \}. \quad (2)$$
Here ${\rm Proj}_S: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^S$ is the projection onto the coordinates indexed by $S$.

It seems that (1) and (2) do not match. If we want (1), (2) to be same, we need to change (1) to:
$$
{X}_{w}^{\circ} = \{ \mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{Fl}_n: \dim(F_p \cap F_q^{st}) = \# \{i \le p: w(i) \le q\}, \forall p,q \in [1,n] \}.
$$
Which definition of (1) and (2) are correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: Interesting question, waiting to see how it pans out, Cotton...